# How to URL Encode Big Sparql files?

Tags: curl, urlencode, graphdb

I have big sparql files (`file.rq`) with INSERT and DELETE statements. My purpose is to use the below curl command to execute them in my repo named TestRepo:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/csv' --data-binary '@file.rq' 'http://localhost:7200/repositories/TestRepo/statements'
```

For filling small `file.rq` files, I encode manually the content by using 
[https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

and then replace `file.rq` by `update=output of above link`.
Everything works without problems. Yet, this is a solution for small files.

QUESTION:
Is there a command line way to url encode the very big `file.rq` files I have? Think that I issue an update process divided into batches, and each batch is a separate `file.rq` file that is very large to manually copy and paste into above URL encode link. So, I want a command line program that can do it. Namely, something like `urlencode file.rq encoded_output.txt`, where `urlencode` is the command line program, `file.rq` is the big sparql file and `encoded_output.txt` is the URL encoded `file.rq`.

Needless to say that I want a tested and trustworthy solution.

Answer (score 0):

According the [SPARQL 1.1 protocol specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#update-via-post-direct), you can submit a direct update with the MIME type `application/sparql-update`, your cURL should look like:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/sparql-update' --data-binary @file.rq 'http://localhost:7200/repositories/TestRepo/statements'
```